# value is ushort returning false for values like 0, 100 etc even if it is ushort

Tags: c#, types

I have a requirement where I need to determine specifically that an object value is ushort, short, int, long or double, like the below code.

```
string dataType = "";
object value = 0;
 if (value is ushort)
                {
                    dataType = "ushort";
                }
                else if (value is short)
                {
                    dataType = "short";
                }
                else if (value is int || value is long
                   || value is ulong  || value is double)
                {
                    dataType = "int";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataType = "float";
                }
```

But the line

```
if (value is ushort)
```

is false for 0 or any other value less than 65535. Why is it so. It qualifies to an ushort right?
Thanks

I have checked with value is ushort for values like 0, 100,200 etc. All are false.

Comment: the value and type are different things. if you use the number literal, it's type will be `int`

Comment: Maybe the [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint16.tryparse?view=net-7.0) function could be useful in this case

Comment: `object value = 0;` is logically equivalent to `int unnamed = 0; object value = unnamed;`. This should tell you what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

A box has a type. A boxed object is only `is ushort` if the box was created **from a `ushort`** (or a `ushort?` due to the special boxing rules for `Nullable<T>`).

An `int` with value 0, when boxed, is still a boxed `int`. It doesn't become a `ushort` just from the scale of the value. `is` is not the same as "could be fitted into a"

Comment: THanks for the quick response. Then what is the best way to determine "could be fitted into a" ushort or short or int?

Comment: @Geervani you'd have to unbox it based on the type (perhaps using `GetType`  / `Type.GetTypeCode`), and then test the unboxed value against expected ranges.

Comment: @Geervani `int value = 0; if (value >= ushort.MinValue && value <= ushort.MaxValue) { dataType = "ushort"; }`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to cast the number literal to `ushort` before boxing it, otherwise it's type if going to be `int` by default:

```cs
object value = (ushort)0;
```